# How to add slash to quotes in JS string?

Tags: javascript

There is the following example of string:

```
var s = "abcdwq'xx'x";
```

How can I screen ordinary quotes, i.e. add slash? I tried to use the following code:

```
s.replace('/(["\'\])/g', "\\$1")
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

Don't put the regular expression in quotes, that makes it an ordinary string.

```js
var s = "abcdwq'xx'x";
console.log(s.replace(/(["'])/g, "\\$1"));
```

Also, you were escaping the `]` that ends `[`.

If you just want to escape single quotes, you don't need the brackets or capture group. Just do:

```js
var s = "abcdwq'xx'x";
console.log(s.replace(/'/g, "\\'"));
```

Comment: i.e. you mean I should remove [ and ] from my regexp?

Comment: @malcoauri No, `\]` escapes the `]` so it no longer represents the close of the character class. In other words `/[\]/` is an invalid regular expression.

Comment: @malcoauri No, I mean you shouldn't have backslash before `]`.

Comment: @Barmar - also, can you please tell me - should I have double quote in [] or  I should remove it? I need to escape only ordinary quotes

Comment: If you only want to escape single quotes, then you don't need double quotes in there.